# Cross platform C++ XML for storing settings

Tags: c++, xml, cross-platform

I am looking for C++ lib for XML.
I know there are some questions on stackoverflow.com about it but still can't choose the one

I found these:

- Boost property tree
- TinyXml (or ticpp)
- PugiXml

What is required:

- crossplatform (!)
- handy API
- lightweight
- stable

I do not really need speed and also boost::asio is already using
I read that TinyXml have some leaks, thus don't like it

What is the most appropriate for my requirenments?

This moment I'm thinking about Pugixml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already use Boost, it is a good idea to use Boost property tree. I started to use it in the same situation, when I already used Boost for another purposes. From my experience, it meets all your conditions.

However, don't expect simple API: there is no simple XML toolkit because of tree XML structure.

For new project, which doesn't use Boost, I would think about another header-only library.

Comment: thx a lot! I'll try. As I can see it was developed especially for storing settings in different formats

Answer (score 1):

[PugiXml](http://pugixml.org/) is my choice. Really easy to start even for beginner, nice documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good comparison table [here](http://lars.ruoff.free.fr/xmlcpp/).